# Configure Microsoft Automate Approval with multiple approvers

Tags: power-automate

I am creating an approval process for Microsoft Automate where I want multiple users to approve a SharePoint item.

I have the flow set to start and wait for approval after a user enters an item but when I put multiple addresses in the assigned to, it concatenates the responses in the outcome and so my conditional response doesn't work.

Here is a screenshot of a test scenario that I set up:

[image: strong text]

I could account for all scenarios but all the documentation that I read shows that if all approvers approve the outcome should be approve and if anyone rejects, that should be the outcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Provide the images from your code, not from run history. And show us how you are entering multiple email ids of approvers. Instead of mask use fake email ids to show the code. Include the condition part also where you are facing the challenge

Comment: Hi Gandalf, thanks for the response, I was able to find a work around.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately with more research, it looks like the outcome is always returned as a comma delimited list when you have more than one approver. I got around this by using nested conditions (I have 3 custom responses in my approval flow)

[image]